# how to add new spinner same as the first one that taking data from database?

Tags: android, android-intent

how to add new spinner same as the first one that taking data from database?
i dont know how to do it, or maybe im not understanding how to do it.
im newbie to android
i copied the code from google
here is my code :

```
public class EnterGeneralDetails extends Activity {

ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
Spinner sp;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_general_details);

    sp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner22);
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_layout,R.id.txt,listItems);
    sp.setAdapter(adapter);


}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    BackTask bt = new BackTask();
    bt.execute();
}

private class BackTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    ArrayList<String> list;
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        list=new ArrayList<>();
    }
    protected Void doInBackground(Void...params){
        InputStream is=null;
        String result="";
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost= new HttpPost("http://thecapitalcitychurch.16mb.com/new/CohortName.php");
            HttpResponse response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            // Get our response as a String.
            is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //convert response to string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result+=line;
            }
            is.close();
            //result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // parse json data
        try{
            JSONArray jArray =new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject=jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                // add interviewee name to arraylist
                list.add(jsonObject.getString("Cohort_Name"));
            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        listItems.addAll(list);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: do you want to create another spinner with the same data?

Comment: no ...i want to add another spinner that would take data from database..with different data...

Comment: So you need the procedure to take data from database? or set that data in spinner? or both?

Comment: do you already have a database? did you implemented a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper?

Comment: i do have a database...and im not using sqlite...im connecting app directly to mysql database

Comment: then create anthor `spinner` in `xml` and `Actvity` and set new `list`  with `ArrayAdapter` of which u getting in `onPostExecute`

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a method to return the data from database to an arraylist. It will look like this:

```
public ArrayList<YourInfoClass> getList() {
    ArrayList<YourInfoClass> array_list = new ArrayList<>();

    //get your data to the array_list. 
    //It depends on your implementation,
    //and return array_list

    return  array_list;
}
```

Now create another arraylist inside the activity in which you need the new spinner, You can save the data from database to this arraylist.Like this:

```
mList = getList();
```

next,define an ArrayAdapter and set the data you got from the database to that adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_layout,R.id.txt,mList);
```

declare a new spinner. Let It be spinner2:

```
Spinner spinner2;
```

Set the adapter to that spinner:

```
spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now you got a new spinner with the data from your database.

Whenever there is a change in the mList, You just need to call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```